# It's possible to store game info on facebook?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, cocos2d-x

I'm making a game with the map, where shows the levels of player, like in Candy Crush. I need to show player's friends near levels, which they achieved. I can retrieve friends and their avatars from Facebook, but I need to know, which level they achieved, to set them the right place. I’m using Cocos2d-x 3.8.1 and Facebook SDK v.4.7.
So, my question: which is the preferred way to store data about levels? Can Facebook keep game's info, or I need to use only third-party servers, like Parse.com? I looked for this in .h files Facebook’s SDK and in SDKBOX, but I found nothing.
If storing on Facebook is possible, I would see the Facebook methods for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store that on your own, there is no API for levels and stuff. There is only the Scores API and the Achievements API:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/achievements

How you store additional game info is up to you. You can use your own server with MySQL, MongoDB or whatever you like. Or you can use a cloud storage provider like Parse.

Comment: I have not used Scores API. I think I can adapt it in my case. Is this possible to use it, but don't show the created with `/USER_ID/scores` values on the Facebook wall?

Comment: no, that´s totally up to facebook. you should not use the scores api for levels though, that´s just....weird. use it for scores.